# Changing child element background color using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I am trying my best:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("tab active");
var child = element.firstElementChild;
child.style.color = '#ffffff';
child.style.backgroundColor = '#004831';
```

```html
<li class="tab active">
  <a href="#">
    Annual Report
  </a>
 </li>
```

This link same as above: https://jsfiddle.net/zxcc0rce/3/

Still not working, is there something missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `element` is not an element.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve active tab anchor styling, then you can do with css

Comment: yes, sorry if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementsByClassName will give you a list of elements and you need choose which one of them you want to apply your style.

in your case, change this line :

```
var child = element[0].firstElementChild;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zxcc0rce/4/

Answer (score 0):

Amended your fiddle so it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/zxcc0rce/5/

Here is how I fixed it:

I changed this line from

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("tab active");
```

to

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("tab active")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with css styling

```css
.active a {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #004831
}
```

```html
<li class="tab active">
  <a href="#">
    Annual Report
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="tab">
  <a href="#">
    Annual Report
  </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this does not work is because **getElementsByClassName** returns a list of all the matching elements.

So to fix it you can simply use the first element in that list:

```
var child = element[0].firstElementChild;
```